# Static webpage textarea not responding to keyboard input on Twitter Bootstrap example

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, text

I am working on a static webpage (using the Twitter Bootstrap carousel example), and the webpage contains a form. I am trying to put the form over the carousel image, but when I do this, the user cannot type in text to the input textarea. I tested this on Chrome and Safari on both my laptop and mobile, and the textbox is always unresponsive to changes. Naturally curious, I looked at W3 School's carousel example, and even on that, no text goes in the textbox when the user types. Here is the link to W3Schools in case you want to try it and see:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel2&stacked=h

Does anyone know what could be causing this behavior?

My code is listed below:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="images/placeholder.jpg">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <center>

            <h1>Behavioral therapy outside the clinician's office.</h1>
            <p>
              <div class="img-rounded" style="background-color: black; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
                <br>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form" background="black">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Name:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="name">
                  </div>
                  &nbsp;
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                  </div>
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up today</button>
                </form>
                </br>
              </div>

            </p>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it has white font by default, have you tried changing the `color` of your text box?

Comment: @brbcoding I tried that - it is not the problem. The cursor doesn't even move when I type.

Comment: Hmm... does **[this](http://jsbin.com/qecijobeye/edit?html,js,output)** page work for you?

Comment: @brbcoding Yes, that page works.

Comment: Maybe try a different version of bootstrap? I just threw the latest version on that page and pasted your code and it worked.

Comment: @brbcoding Thanks, you are right - the problem was the version of Bootstrap i was using.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the problem was the version of Bootstrap used! I was using the version 4 alpha version of Bootstrap, which apparently is still buggy. Switching to Bootstrap 3.3.5 fixes the problem.

(Thanks to brbcoding for pointing this out!)